# List Delphi API Calls from EXE

Tags: delphi

I have an EXE file and someone that wants to know what all the API calls that the program uses. Short of trying to decompile the EXE, is there a way to run a program or otherwise get a list of all the API calls that the program has? I was told that they believe the program was written in Delphi, but they are not sure. So preferably a solution oriented to Delphi and perhaps a broader way for any EXE type file. we don't need the source, just how we are supposed to interact with the program.

Comment: If you're not sure it was written in Delphi, then that suggests you don't have the source code (or else you could just look at it and see what language it is). Without the source, the language doesn't really matter.

Comment: than the question is how do i get an API list from a program of unknown origin?

Comment: that depends how obfuscated those calls are. There is not `strace` in Windows for what i know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) be of any use?

Comment: possibly, looks to provide the functions which is what is needed. Will definitely give it a try. thank you

Comment: It says it lists called functions; does it really do that, or does it merely list *imported* functions?

Comment: It likely just lists the imported functions. But if a DLL function is not actually called in the EXE's code, it should not appear in the EXE's imports table to begin with.

Comment: @RobKennedy It just lists imported functions upon load, but there's a profile function that puts out a log of what seems to be actually "called" functions.  For instance: "GetProcAddress(0x77DD0000 [ADVAPI32.DLL], "RegOpenKeyExA") called from "WMP.DLL" at address 0x12A527AF and returned 0x77DD7852."